# Lombok and Maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, lombok

I'm trying to use Lombok with Maven and VRaptor on IntelliJ but it doesn't work.

I already read some info in stackoverflow but none solved my problem, i already enabled the Annotation Processor in Intellij but still nothing.

I tryied to compile it from command-line too (Windows) and didn't work.

I also tryed to create another project without maven and add the library, create some classes for test and it works, compile and run perfectly.

Any help?

The project has only 2 class, 1 entity and 1 controller

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>razor</groupId>
<artifactId>controle-de-ponto</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<description>Um sistema de controlo de ponto</description>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>projectlombok.org</id>
        <url>http://projectlombok.org/mavenrepo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <weld.version>2.1.2.Final</weld.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.com.caelum</groupId>
        <artifactId>vraptor</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.6</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-core-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-cdi</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <!-- uncomment this line on app servers -->
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.34</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.com.caelum.vraptor</groupId>
        <artifactId>vraptor-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.com.caelum.vraptor</groupId>
        <artifactId>vraptor-java8</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>controle-de-ponto</finalName>
    <!--<outputDirectory>/Users/turini/Documents/workspace/vraptor4/vraptor-blank-project/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>-->
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Error when i try to compile:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building controle-de-ponto 0.0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ controle-de-ponto ---
[INFO] Using 'ISO-8859-1' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ controle-de-ponto ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Users\Kennedy\Desktop\controle-de-ponto\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Kennedy/Desktop/controle-de-ponto/src/main/java/br/com/caelum/vraptor/controller/IndexController.java:[37,16] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setNome(java.lang.String)
  location: variable usuario of type org.razor.cponto.beans.Usuario
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.167 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-02-04T13:41:01-02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/204M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project controle-de-ponto: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Kennedy/Desktop/controle-de-ponto/src/main/java/br/com/caelum/vraptor/controller/IndexController.java:[37,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method setNome(java.lang.String)
[ERROR] location: variable usuario of type org.razor.cponto.beans.Usuario
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Could you be more specific than "it didn't work"? What was the error?

Comment: I edited my question with more info.

Comment: the Usuario class has the annotation @Data. And the setNome is generated by it.

Comment: @StephaneM i added more info.

Comment: I wonder if they made it possible to work with any IDE that is not Eclipse.

Comment: i'l try to same project on eclipse to see if it builds.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should work as is, and has nothing to do with IntelliJ idea. But I would:

- make sure the `@Data` annotation is the lombok one
- remove the repository definition (maven central is fine)
- use a recent lombok version ([1.16.0](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.projectlombok%7Clombok%7C1.16.0%7Cjar) *as of this writing*)
- rebuild (`mvn clean package`)

I think the lombok jar is not found by maven in your case or that you might have another `@Data`.

Comment: Thx! Looks like was the version, i didn't see i was using an old version. Shame on me haha.

Comment: It's more likely to be the repo: browse http://projectlombok.org/mavenrepo/ and you'll see it doesn't look like a maven repo.

Comment: mvn clean package and then removing the old war file. Replacing with new one. And then after deployment. Bazinga :D +1

Answer (score 76):

This might work

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>1.16.12</version>
                    </path>                         
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Latest versions:

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin
- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok

Comment: Thanks, took me hours and your solution fixed it.
Working with `maven-compiler-plugin` `3.6.2` and `lombok` `1.16.16`

Comment: This works, but unexpectedly moving lombok dependency to the beginning of `<dependencies>` list also helped. `maven-compiler-plugin 3.7.0` `lombok 1.18.0`

Comment: According documentation this is for Java 9+ - https://projectlombok.org/setup/maven

Comment: Opened my eyes. Thanks when I added another annotation processor (for map struct) lombok stopped working and I was not realising the issue being caused by the now missing implicit declaration of the annotation processor. Took me too many hours ...

Comment: Same issue as @KevinKussmaul ... it saved me !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.16</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the projectId tag, try to replace `projectlombok.org` with `org.projectlombok`

Answer (score -1):

```
<dependency>  
  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId> 
  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

this should solve the problem same issue on my vs code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -6):

You need add lombok plugin:

```
  <build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.16.8.0</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>generate-sources</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>delombok</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: no, this is for  replacing the Lombok annotations with equivalent source code