# Maven fails to pull in dependencies and compile fails

Tags: java, maven

I am fairly new to Maven and trying to compile a very simple project. This is my `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.bharani.aws</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.bharani.aws.dynamo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.106</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.16.16</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

When I do `mvn compile`, I get a bunch of `cannot find symbol` errors. Clearly, the dependencies are not downloaded and used. Here is the error log:

```
f45c89aa1b75:bharani-aws-dynamo janakiab$ mvn compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building com.bharani.aws.dynamo 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ com.bharani.aws.dynamo ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ com.bharani.aws.dynamo ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[3,54] package com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[4,54] package com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[5,54] package com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[6,54] package com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[7,14] package lombok does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[8,14] package lombok does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[9,14] package lombok does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[10,14] package lombok does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[11,14] package lombok does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[16,2] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Data
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[17,2] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Builder
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[18,2] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class ToString
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[19,2] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class NoArgsConstructor
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[20,2] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class AllArgsConstructor
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[21,2] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class DynamoDBTable
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[3,26] package com.amazonaws.auth does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[4,26] package com.amazonaws.auth does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[5,29] package com.amazonaws.regions does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[6,41] package com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2 does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[7,41] package com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2 does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[8,54] package com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[33,13] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class AmazonDynamoDB
  location: class com.bharani.aws.Main
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[41,44] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class AmazonDynamoDB
  location: class com.bharani.aws.Main
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[41,13] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DynamoDBMapper
  location: class com.bharani.aws.Main
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[24,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
  location: class com.bharani.aws.CustomerInfo
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[25,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DynamoDBHashKey
  location: class com.bharani.aws.CustomerInfo
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[28,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DynamoDBAttribute
  location: class com.bharani.aws.CustomerInfo
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[31,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DynamoDBAttribute
  location: class com.bharani.aws.CustomerInfo
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[34,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DynamoDBAttribute
  location: class com.bharani.aws.CustomerInfo
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[37,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DynamoDBAttribute
  location: class com.bharani.aws.CustomerInfo
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[40,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DynamoDBAttribute
  location: class com.bharani.aws.CustomerInfo
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[22,15] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class AmazonDynamoDB
  location: class com.bharani.aws.Main
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[23,15] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DynamoDBMapper
  location: class com.bharani.aws.Main
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[36,38] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class AWSStaticCredentialsProvider
  location: class com.bharani.aws.Main
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[37,29] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BasicAWSCredentials
  location: class com.bharani.aws.Main
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[35,29] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Regions
  location: class com.bharani.aws.Main
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[34,16] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder
  location: class com.bharani.aws.Main
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[42,20] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DynamoDBMapper
  location: class com.bharani.aws.Main
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[46,28] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method builder()
  location: class com.bharani.aws.CustomerInfo
[INFO] 39 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.560 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-10-04T18:46:40-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/302M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project com.bharani.aws.dynamo: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[3,54] package com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[4,54] package com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[5,54] package com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[6,54] package com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[7,14] package lombok does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[8,14] package lombok does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[9,14] package lombok does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[10,14] package lombok does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[11,14] package lombok does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[16,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class Data
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[17,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class Builder
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[18,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class ToString
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[19,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class NoArgsConstructor
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[20,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class AllArgsConstructor
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[21,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class DynamoDBTable
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[3,26] package com.amazonaws.auth does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[4,26] package com.amazonaws.auth does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[5,29] package com.amazonaws.regions does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[6,41] package com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2 does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[7,41] package com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2 does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[8,54] package com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[33,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class AmazonDynamoDB
[ERROR] location: class com.bharani.aws.Main
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[41,44] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class AmazonDynamoDB
[ERROR] location: class com.bharani.aws.Main
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[41,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class DynamoDBMapper
[ERROR] location: class com.bharani.aws.Main
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[24,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
[ERROR] location: class com.bharani.aws.CustomerInfo
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[25,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class DynamoDBHashKey
[ERROR] location: class com.bharani.aws.CustomerInfo
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[28,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class DynamoDBAttribute
[ERROR] location: class com.bharani.aws.CustomerInfo
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[31,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class DynamoDBAttribute
[ERROR] location: class com.bharani.aws.CustomerInfo
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[34,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class DynamoDBAttribute
[ERROR] location: class com.bharani.aws.CustomerInfo
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[37,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class DynamoDBAttribute
[ERROR] location: class com.bharani.aws.CustomerInfo
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/CustomerInfo.java:[40,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class DynamoDBAttribute
[ERROR] location: class com.bharani.aws.CustomerInfo
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[22,15] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class AmazonDynamoDB
[ERROR] location: class com.bharani.aws.Main
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[23,15] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class DynamoDBMapper
[ERROR] location: class com.bharani.aws.Main
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[36,38] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class AWSStaticCredentialsProvider
[ERROR] location: class com.bharani.aws.Main
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[37,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class BasicAWSCredentials
[ERROR] location: class com.bharani.aws.Main
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[35,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable Regions
[ERROR] location: class com.bharani.aws.Main
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[34,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder
[ERROR] location: class com.bharani.aws.Main
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[42,20] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class DynamoDBMapper
[ERROR] location: class com.bharani.aws.Main
[ERROR] /Users/janakiab/code/bharani-aws-dynamo/src/main/java/com/bharani/aws/Main.java:[46,28] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method builder()
[ERROR] location: class com.bharani.aws.CustomerInfo
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
f45c89aa1b75:bharani-aws-dynamo janakiab$
```

Can someone point me if I am missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325297/lombok-and-maven? The last comment. There's a way to configure your <build> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dependencies are defined inside of the < dependencyManagement > section. In this section it defines dependencies in a parent project and allows the same version to be used in sub-modules. If you remove the < dependencyManagement > tags and/or add the same thing in just < dependencies > and it should work properly.

See [maven dependency management page](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Also, for direct dependency, to import everything, I should have done:

    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.106</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-project-maven.html